# Higher-dimensional version of Fenchel's theorem that total curvature is $\ge 2 \pi$

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, knot-theory

> ***Q***. Is there a higher-dimensional version of the theorem due to Fenchel that the
> total curvature of a closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $\ge 2\pi$,
> with equality only if the curve is planar and convex?

Here the *total curvature* is
$\int \kappa(s) \, ds$.
Fáry & Milnor subsequently proved that if the curve is knotted, then the total curvature
is strictly greater than $2\pi$. (Apologies if I have misinterpreted the history.)

By "higher-dimensional" I mean a result addressing the "total
curvature" (appropriately defined)
of a closed, compact (hyper-)surface in $\mathbb{R}^d$, $d>3$.
In other words, I am seeking a generalization of the curve to a (hyper-)surface,
rather than a generalization of a 1D curve to $\mathbb{R}^d$, which I understand is addressed by Fáry/Milnor.

---

> Milnor, John. "On total curvatures of closed space curves." *Mathematica Scandinavica* (1954): 289-296.
> ([Jstor link](http://www.jstor.org/stable/24488936), [eudml link](https://eudml.org/doc/165509).)

Comment: See papers of Chern and Lashof on the total curvature of immersed submanifolds.

Comment: @DeaneYang: Thanks! Chern, Shiing-shen, and Richard K. Lashof. "On the total curvature of immersed manifolds." *American Journal of Mathematics* 79.2 (1957): 306-318.

Comment: You may also like this one by Kuiper and Meeks: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214441483   Kuiper has several nice surveys on this topic.